# About responsive layout and display none some elements

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a responsive layout for mobiles at the moment, with media queries that load the current css for each type of screen size. I'm doing `display:none;` for some elements that i don't want to show on mobile or desktop.

My question is about the performance. I have many elements/divs that i need to rework on mobile screens that i think to display none the desktop elements and show the current.

If i use this method, the browser will process **all** display:none elements? I can get a **less performance** if this happens?

**If so, what's the better what to do that without impacting the performance?**

Assuming a mobile first approach. Is it possible to load a section of content only if the screen is over a certain width?

I understand how to show/hide content depending on screen size using CSS media queries. But what if you want to avoid unnecessarily loading content that will hidden on smaller screens.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

-- EDIT:

I'm trying to understand this method but without success:

I have put this script inside the main html page:

```
<script>
    var url = screen.width > 1024 ? '/api-test.php' : '/api-test2.php';
    fetch(url).then(response => document.querySelector(".containerAnime2").innerHTML = response);
</script>
```

And inside the "api-test.php" i put the div that i want to load:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <div class="containerAnime2">
        <div class="animeinfoLeft">
            <img src="/images/background_animes/<?= $get_anime['url_nome']; ?>.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="animeinfoRight">
            <p><?= $get_anime['nome']; ?> Todos os Episódios Online</p>
            <div class="extra">
                <span class="elementExtra"><img src="/images/star-icon.png" style="width:16px; height:16px;vertical-align:-1px;"/> <?= $get_anime['nota']; ?></span>
                <span class="elementExtra"><img src="/images/iconDate.png" style="width:16px; height:16px;vertical-align:-1px;"/> <?= $get_anime['ano']; ?></span>
                <span class="elementExtra"><?= $episodios_count['0']; ?> Episódio<?= (($episodios_count['0'] > 1) ? 's' : ''); ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="tags">
                <?php foreach ($tags_array as $genero) {
                    echo '<a href="/letras/'. $genero .'/"><span class="elementTag">'. $genero .'</span></a>';
                } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <p><?= $get_anime['nome']; ?> Todos os Episódios Online, Assistir <?= $get_anime['nome']; ?> Anime Completo, Assistir <?= $get_anime['nome']; ?> Online.<br><br><?= $description; ?></p>
            </div>
            <a href="#">
                <div class="errorButton">
                    RELATAR ERRO OU EPISÓDIO NOVO
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

**But it not worked yet.. i have made something wrong?**

I got this error on chrome:
`(index):129 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`

Comment: `document.querySelector(".containerAnime2")` is null according to your error. It looks like `.containerAnime2` is inside your response, not on your initial page load. You have to inject your HTML into an element that already exisits on the page

Comment: Performance would depend on a bunch of factors. Looks like you're overwriting `document.querySelector('.containerAnime2')`'s HTML. If you only have a few Elements that don't rely on `fetch` or the `XMLHttpRequest` then it would be faster to create the Elements first. Just hide the Elements not in use and don't use the `fetch` stuff. If you don't need to rely on the Server to build the Elements, then don't. Oh... your `respose` is just a `Body` Object. You would have to `response.text().then(txt=>{ /* txt is text */ })`.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes, the performance will be affected because the browser will need to download all of the HTML in its request response, including items that are display none. The likelihood of any user noticing that will be negligible unless you are talking about tens of thousands of DOM elements that make the browser download an HTML file that is megabytes in size.

If you are very concerned about this, then one solution would be to look at the browser's user-agent on the server and respond with appropriate HTML based on if the user-agent string matches something similar to a mobile device.

Another option would be to load the content dynamically through JavaScript based on the screen dimensions. You'd make an API call to retrieve either mobile or desktop and the server would respond with the appropriate HTML content.

For example:

```
var url = screen.width > 1024 ? '/my/api/desktop' : '/my/api/mobile';

fetch(url).then(response => document.querySelector("#container").innerHTML = response);
```

Comment: Have some better way to do that?

Comment: You could look at  the user-agent string on the server side and return appropriate HTML based on that. Or use JavaScript to make an API request and retrieve the appropriate content based on the screen dimensions.

Comment: I think with php is more complicated.. i'm trying to use javascript but it's not working. i tried with: <script>if ((screen.width>1024)) {</script> <div1></div> <script>}</script>. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I added an example. Inline scripts tags like that will not work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm trying to understand but i don't understood at all whats means the "API" and it get a bit confused to me.. i put this script at the html header and leave the #container div empty, so i load the content from the "api link"?

Comment: Yes. The API is just another name for a server. Use whatever URL path your server requires and create two endpoints (desktop and mobile) to call from your JavaScript page.

Comment: I'm trying to do that method without success yet.. i have edited the post with the details and what i have did.. could you try to help me and check what i did wrong? thank you!